# C++ program unable to run with interruption that "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000000d)"

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am using visual studio 2010 in windows 7, i am running Normal distribution code which uses pcl header files. The entire code is in cpp. While debugging i am get an application error
 " The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000000d). click ok to close the application "  in an new window. while i click ok, the window gets closed and programs stops running. In the output tabs, shows unable to load or cannot find pdb files.

Following steps i created the Visual studio project

1. downloaded the pcl trunk version which only consist the header files for Normal distribution
2. using cmake, i created the install visual studio project for installing pcl
3. After creating INSTALL project, installed the pcl headers using visual studio
4. again using cmake, i created the Normal distribution project which make use of installed pcl headers

while running the Normal distribution project, i am getting the above mentioned application error. I am unable to find what is the problem